# Multiple swagger APIs

Tags: rest, api, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm using swagger for documenting my API but now I need to extend this with additional API. Is there a way to create 2 json files (2 APIs) e.a. `/api/v1/public` and `/api/v1/private`
which would share definitions of certain models/controllers but I would need to mark some properties to be only accesssible to certain api.

For example if I have model `users` with columns `name` and `some_internal_id`, is there a way to group these properties so the first one belongs to both API's while
second one only belongs to private API?

Comment: Which language/framework are you using?

Comment: @Zorkan, have you found any solution to this already? If so, mind you posting it as an answer please?

Answer (score 0):

I use php-swagger. In the swagger config file you need to scan multiple times for multiple JSON files. For example, my config looks like this:

```
return [
    'Swagger' => [
        'docs' => [
            'public' => [
                'include' => [
                    ROOT . DS . 'src' . DS . 'Resources' . DS . 'Swagger' . DS . 'Public' . DS . 'Paths',
                    ROOT . DS . 'src' . DS . 'Resources' . DS . 'Swagger' . DS . 'Public' . DS . 'Definitions'
                ]
            ],
            'private' => [
                'include' => [
                    ROOT . DS . 'src' . DS . 'Resources' . DS . 'Swagger' . DS . 'Private' . DS . 'Paths',
                    ROOT . DS . 'src' . DS . 'Resources' . DS . 'Swagger' . DS . 'Private' . DS . 'Definitions'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```